# Why is useState failing to read initialization value?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a modal that includes a form for editing data about cats.  I am passing into that modal the current value of the cat's name along with other attributes in an object called selectedCatData. By using console.log I have verified that selectedCatData and the name field are both being passed into the modal component as props correctly.  When I try using the name as an initialization value in a call to useState it does not set the value and subsequently printing the local state variable "formName" results in undefined.

```
function EditModal(props) {
    let { selectedCatData } = props
    console.log(`EditModal recieved props "name": ${selectedCatData.name}`)
    let [formName, setFormName] = useState(selectedCatData.name)
    console.log(`EditModal copied name to local state: ${formName}`)
```

The first console.log correctly prints "Kitty"
The second consol.log prints "undefined" and this has me vary confused.
I have used useState a lot before and never run into a problem like this.

The saved values exist as state at a height level in my component tree. I want to make a local copy that the form will use to track unsaved changes.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: [Works for me.](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-cerf-x0n53?file=/src/EditModal.js)  Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the code sandbox, I can see that it is working as I would expect there.  What could explain the same code behaving differently in code sandbox and when locally hosted?

Comment: Perhaps a different version of the tools being used?  But honestly, without a [mcve] to demonstrate, the *most common* cause is a mistaken assumption when debugging.

Comment: Did you import `useState` from "react" and not from another random library with your IDE autocompletion? :p

Comment: @dbuchet good guess but no, I was getting useState from React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working and, though I never figured out for sure why the code above did not work, I have a guess.

**Here's how I got it working:**
I switched from the repetitive structure used in the question (that breaks apart selected cat data into several calls to useState) to one that keeps the state as one object. I passed that down one more layer in the component tree to a  and did pretty much the same thing there, setting state like this:
`const [formState, setFormState] = useState({...selectedCatData})`

**Here's my guess as to why that worked:**
The Edit Modal described above never unmounts.  It is always present in the DOM, it just has its display property set to "none" when its "open" prop is false.  By contrast, the  is a child of that modal and is therefore removed from the DOM when its parent is hidden with `display: "none"`.
Because this form is being completely removed and a new React Component created the call to useState that initializes the Form's local state is made each time the Form opens.  When that state was situated in the Edit Modal useState was only being called to initialize the local state one time on the first load of the page.

That, again, is just my best guess as to why moving the state down one layer in the component tree solved my issue. If anyone reading this can confirm or refute that guess I'd love to hear it.